# qemu command to start an iso and include a file.img as hard drive

Tags: qemu

i'm currently using **debian jessie** , and i can't find **qemu launcher** in its repositories .

however i wanted to know how to start or boot an **iso** image and inclure a  *raw file*  (file.img ; created by **dd**) as **hard drive** , also i would like to know how to let qemu use the internet connection in the booted iso .

*how to do that please ?* and **thanks**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's easy, just read qemu-doc.html.

But if you need just quick answer:

`qemu-system-i386 -cdrom /path/to/iso -hda /path/to/file.img -net user -daemonize`

More advanced example (which I always use):

`kvm -name vm -nodefaults -monitor vc -cpu host,-svm -m 1024 -drive file=file.img,media=disk,cache=unsafe -drive file=/path/to/iso,media=cdrom,readonly -net nic,model=rtl8139,macaddr=02:04:06:88:fa:bc -net vde,sock=/tmp/kvmnet.vde -vga vmware -daemonize`

instructs KVM to provide host CPU definition into VM, add 1G memory, put a disk first then cdrom second, add RTL8139 NIC with specified mac address and attach it to VDE switch, then add vmware virtual GPU to have more video modes available and daemonize it.

Comment: thanks a lot my brother ,  but for me i use everything amd64 , is there something else i should know ?

Comment: I glad I helped you! Do you want to run amd64 ISO or do you concern future issues when running qemu on amd64?

Comment: yes i want to run amd64 iso :)

Comment: Then you need your host to be also amd64, or kvm acceleration (if you use any) will not work. However qemu-system-x86_64 must be always available and run amd64 ISO perfectly, so try it out first.

Comment: yes my host os is amd64 ,  and thanks again bro :3